# Reading excel file with multiple sheets in SAS 9.4

Tags: sas

I have an excel file with 50 worksheets AB0 to AB49. Each worksheet consists of 14 columns, with column names same in all the sheets. The first column in every sheet varies from a number from 1 in sheet 1 to 50 in sheet 50. Each sheet has 18262 rows.  I need to read all the sheets together in SAS and print it. I need to do descriptive statistics on Column 5, 9 and 10. Besides I need to draw their occurrence distributions as well in form of graph.

```
proc import DATAFILE = " C:\Personal\Data_2016\data_new.xlsx"
            OUT = data 
            DBMS = xlsx 
            REPLACE;
    SHEET = "AB0"
    GETNAMES = Yes;
run;

proc univariate;   
run;
```

In this code i am getting Moments, Basic Statistical Measures, test for location; Mu = 0, Quantiles,  Extreme Observations as an output for all fourteen columns, where as I want output from all 50 sheets together ( 18262 (in one sheet) * 50 values in each column) for column 5, 9 and 10 only.

Comment: Have you tried importing each file using a loop or call execute, stacking them, and then running your descriptive statistics?

Comment: @superfluous Can you suggest me some example. I never tried it. I am new to SAS.

Comment: In general you should avoid sheet names that can be cell names, it sometimes causes errors in dealing with Excel files. If the column start varies double check your imported data.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to combine them into a single dataset.  Instead of using PROC IMPORT use the XLSX libname engine.

```
 libname in xlsx  'C:\Personal\Data_2016\data_new.xlsx' ;
 data all_data;
   set in.AB0 - in.AB49 ;
 run;
```

You will need to have SAS/Access to PC Files licensed.  But you do not need either Microsoft Windows or Excel software.

Comment: Didn't know this existed - neat!

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this will only work if you have SAS/ACCESS to PCFILES along with the SAS PCFILES SERVER service installed.

Comment: Doesn't need PCFILES Server if you have SAS 9.4.

Comment: @DominicComtois Has nothing to do with PCFILES Server.

Comment: @Tom While running the above code with XLSX libname engine, i am getting the following errors. ERROR: The XLSX engine cannot be found.ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.ERROR: Libref IN is not assigned.

Comment: What version of SAS? Look at automatic macro variable SYSVLONG or the note at the top of you SAS log.  Works with 9.4 (TS1M3).

Comment: @Tom Mine is SAS 9.4 (TS1M1)

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more details on what summary statistics you want we can be of more help to you, but the import is straightforward enough:

```
%macro import_loop;
    %do i = 0 %to 49;
        proc import datafile = "C:\Personal\Data_2016\data_new.xlsx"
            out = import_sheet&i.
            dbms = xlsx replace;
            getnames = yes;
            sheet = "Sheet&i.";
        run;
    %end;
%mend import_loop;

%import_loop;

data stack;
    set import_sheet:;
run;
```

Now you have all 50 datasets stacked and ready to work with.

Comment: When i ran the above code, i am getting ERROR 22-7 Invalid option name XX( 0-49)

Comment: Also another ERROR: The data set list (WORK.import_sheet:) does not contain any members.

Comment: That's because the loop didn't work - try now. Really though, Tom's method is much sleeker; go with that.

Comment: @ superfluous Your code perfectly works now. For summary statistics, i want everything we get from univariate command. Mainly, i want quantiles at 0, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 97.5, 99, 100 %, I want Mean, SD, Standard error mean, Upper 95 % Mean, Lower 95 % Mean, Number of Values, Skewness, Kurtosis, CV, Number  of Zero Values in the column, Mode. In addition, i want to see the distribution of the columns in graphical format. I wish i could attach the output i desire, i got from JMP. But i do need to write the code for same work in SAS.

Comment: Glad the import worked. It might be easiest to ask your other questions in a new question, e.g., "I have a dataset with 14 different columns - how do I do [X, Y, Z]"

Comment: thanks for your advise.  Can you suggest me some tutorial, where i can learn macros statements that you wrote in the code.

Comment: Google is your friend on this one :) - http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/nesug99/bt108.pdf isn't a bad start though

Comment: This is giving me error as  ERROR: Output SAS data set must be provided. --any help on this will be great . Thanks